# HTML elements undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I want to save any element into variable, it ends up being undefined. 
Which in this case is the basketDiv. When I try to append to it it says it is undefined. The html and js are in seperate files. But I don't think taht is the issue because everything else works.

Thanks for help

```js
    function createItemRow(name, price, amount)
    {
    var itemRow = document.createElement('div');
    var basketDiv = this.document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0];
    itemRow.classList.add('item');
    var itemRowHtml = `
    <h2 id="name">${name}</h2>
    <h2 id="amount">Amount: ${amount}</h2>
    <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
    <h2 id="price">${price} Kč</h2>`;
    itemRow.innerHTML = itemRowHtml;
    console.log(basketDiv);
    basketDiv.append(itemRow);
    }
```

```html
    <div class='basket'>
            <div class="item">
                <h2 id="name">Xiaomi Mi A2</h2>
                <h2 id="amount">Amount: 1</h2>
                <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
                <h2 id="price">5000 Kč</h2>
            </div>   
            <div class="item">
                <h2 id="name">Xiaomi Mi A2</h2>
                <h2 id="amount">Amount: 1</h2>
                <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
                <h2 id="price">5000 Kč</h2>
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <h2 id="name">Xiaomi Mi A2</h2>
                <h2 id="amount">Amount: 1</h2>
                <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
                <h2 id="price">5000 Kč</h2>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: what does `this` mean?

Comment: post code, not images.

Comment: FYI: ids are supposed to be singular in a document and you keep repeating them,

Comment: What variable is undefined?

Comment: Do not use images for codes. Post it as code itself so that the people trying to help you can copy it and work

Comment: first of all, id must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function actually works, maybe you try to get the element before page rended

```js
function createItemRow(name, amount, price) {
    var itemRow = document.createElement('div');
    var basketDiv = this.document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0];
    itemRow.classList.add('item');
    var itemRowHtml = `
    <h2 class="name"> ${name}</h2>
    <h2 class="amount">Amount: ${amount}</h2>
    <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
    <h2 class="price">${price} Kč</h2>`;
    itemRow.innerHTML = itemRowHtml;
    console.log(basketDiv);
    basketDiv.append(itemRow);
}
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="createItemRow('toto', 50, 10)">createItemRow</button> 
 <div class='basket'>
     <div class="item">
       <h2 id="name">Xiaomi Mi A2</h2>
       <h2 id="amount">Amount: 1</h2>
       <h2 class="close">X</h2>                
       <h2 id="price">5000 Kč</h2>
     </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that was it, even though I had code which I thought would wait till the site was fully loaded, but when I tried different code to wait for the html it worked.

Comment: make sure you do have div basket before call the function. even there is no class 'basket', getElementsByClassName return a collection, if the collection is empty, `document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0]; ` will be undefined.